# Sylius : new entity grid not executing

Tags: symfony, sylius

I'm using [Sylius](http://www.sylius.org/) alpha version,
i created a new entity following this docs :
[sylius docs](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/cookbook/custom-model.html/)
but when  i try to change a filed label in the grid or add a filed nothing changes in the create form even when i clear the cache. I think there's a lack of documentation.
**app/config/grids/admin/category.yml:**

```
sylius_grid:
grids:
    app_admin_category:
        driver:
            name: doctrine/orm
            options:
                class: AppBundle\Entity\Category
        fields:
            name:
                type: string
                label: sylius.ui.name
            taxon:
                type: string
                label: sylius.ui.taxon

        actions:
            main:
                create:
                    type: create
            item:
                update:
                    type: update
                delete:
                    type: delete
```

**app/config/routing/admin/category.yml:**

```
app_admin_category:
resource: |
    alias: app.category
    section: admin
    templates: SyliusAdminBundle:Crud
    redirect: update
    grid: app_admin_category
    vars:
        all:
            subheader: app.ui.category
        index:
            icon: 'file image outline'
type: sylius.resource
```